# Flask unit test throwing Error: has no attribute 'csrf_token' in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-unittest, flask-wtforms

In my unit test I have a already disabled the CSRF using

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

An example test case that fails

```
def test_get_tags(self):
    tag_name = 'tag_1'
    r = self.client.get(url_for('tag.tags'))
    self.assertIn(tag_name, r.get_data(as_text=True))
```

But in my template I have called the csrf  token.

```
{% for form in tag_forms%}
    {{form.csrf_token}}
    {{form.tag_name}}
    {{form.update}}
    {{form.delete}}
{% endfor %}
```

This leads to the following error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'app.tag.forms.UpdateTagForm object' has no attribute 'csrf_token'
```

I am guessing that this error is due to the fact that I have diabled the CSRF Token. How to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your jinja template first check to see if the value is set, and then if it is include it.

```
{% if 'csrf_token' in form %}
  {{form.csrf_token}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This works for me. I have already up-voted. Can someone confirm if this is the "standard" way to do this?

Comment: Something must have changed in more recent versions of WTForms (or maybe Flask-WTF) so that this workaround is no longer needed. I can set `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` to False in my Flask config and `{{ form.csrf_token }}` will simply be ignored inside of templates.

Comment: It's possible they just defaulted it to a null or empty string, which is really what makes sense there.